# Attempt at prove that rank theorem implies that the image of this function with constant rank is a manifold

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, solution-verification, manifolds

Let $f:U\rightarrow U$, $U\subseteq\mathbb{R^m}$ open, such that $f\circ f = f$ and let $M=f(U)$. I showed that there exists neighborhood $V\subseteq U$ of M such that $f$ has constant rank on $V$, let us say $\text{rank}(f'(x))=n$ for each $x\in V$ . Now I need to prove that $M$ is a manifold.

My attempt is as follows: given $x\in M$, by the constant rank theorem, there exists diffeomorphisms $\alpha: Y\times N\rightarrow Z$ and $\beta: Z\rightarrow Y\times W$ such that $Y\times W$, $Y\times N \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}\times\mathbb{R^{m-n}}$, $Z\subseteq V$ are all open such that $x=f(x)\in Z$ and $(\beta\circ f\circ\alpha)(y,w)=(y,0)$. By taking $\phi: Y\rightarrow Z$, $\phi(y)=\beta^{-1}(y,0)$ there exists unique $(y,w)\in Y\times W$ such that $\phi(y)=\beta^{-1} (y,0)=(f\circ\alpha(y,w))\in M $, that is $\phi(Y)\subseteq M\cap Z$. Also, $\phi$ is a homeomorphism (with inverse $\pi\beta|_\phi(Y)$, where $\pi:Y\times N\rightarrow Y$ is the projection $\pi(y,n)=(y,0)$) with injective derivative (because of $\beta^{-1}$), hence a parametrization from $Y$ to a neighborhood (in $M$) of $x$.

Is that the correct idea? Also, any other proof or intuition always helps.